# Como clonar una rama especifica de mi repositorio de Github a mi servidor Nginx

Tags: github, nginx

Intento clonar mi repositorio de **Github** a mi servidor **Nginx** y me aparece el siguiente error:

**git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

He colocado el siguiente comando:

```
git clone --branch master git@github.com:Danielbn64/e-comerce07-03-2023.git
```

La razón de esto es que cometi el error novato y descuidado de subir mi repositorio a github en una rama que no era la rama por defecto: **main**

Y ya no se como hacer que me coja la rama correcta: **master**

Si escribo por ejemplo:

```
git clone git@github.com:Danielbn64/e-comerce07-03-2023.git
```

Si me la coje, pero alli no tengo nada solo un README.
¿Como clono el repositorio que se encuentra en la rama master?

Comment: La rama existe en el origin?

Comment: No lo se ¿Cómo compruebo eso?

Comment: Yendo a github y mirando qué ramas hay

Comment: Si existe la rama master